# DEP6953: Failed to launch remote debugger

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2017, hololens, hololens-emulator, windows-mixed-reality

## **My setup**

HoloLens
Windows 10 October 2018 Update (10.0.17763.134)

### Desktop

Windows 10 Enterprise
Visual Studio Community 2017 Version
Unity 2018.2.19f1 (Latest 7th December 2018 Update)

### The Problem

I am unable to deploy any application to the HoloLens, but able to deploy it on hololens-emulator. I'm attempting with the Origami application exported from Unity as in the tutorial.I always get the same error "

> DEP6953: Failed to launch remote debugger with the following error:
>
> 'Command failed: 0x80070020'

I'm at a loss for what else to try, or what setting I've missed. I've reset the HoloLens several times and reinstalled Visual Studio only to get the same thing.

I have already tried the solution mentioned on Windows Mixed Reality Developer Forum https://forums.hololens.com/discussion/7361/deployment-error-dep6953 but it didn't work for me.

Comment: @halfer  I have used the same format for asking questions which I generally use for asking question but both errors are different with different problems.

Comment: Ah, OK - apologies. I recommend avoiding copy+paste for this exact reason. I'll withdraw the dup vote.

Comment: @halfer No problem. Thanks for informing, I will keep this thing in mind from next time.

Answer (score 1):

For whom it may be usefull.
I got this error deploying and debugging windows iot on a raspberry pi.

I fixed this by changing the authentication mode to 'none'. then deployment succeeded.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It could be anything. You need to investigate the Hololens logs. Open "Windows Device Portal"/System/Logging.

Then you need to select some providers with severity by choosing them in box and clicking "Enable". I usually begin from "Microsoft-Windows-WinRT-Error" ETW provider.

DO NOT CLOSE THE LOGGING PAGE!!!!!

Start the debugger with app, see the error and go to Logging page. Try to find out the root of issue.